# Why can my Java project call my DLLs successfully in Eclipse when I place them in JAVA_HOME\jre6\bin but failed in using java.library.path?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface, java.library.path

After doing some research, some people say I can add the following **VM Argument** in my project **Run Configuration**. In run time, JVM will search these directories to find DDLs.

```
-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc}/GunCalibration/myLib/DLLs;${env_var:PATH}"
```

**GunCalibration** is my Java project folder in my workspace.
**DLLs** folder contains all my DLLs which are defined with my JNI specification.

As a result, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Software
>   x64\eclipse3.7\Kai\workspace_RealW\GunCalibration\myLib\DLLs\sixense.dll:
>   Can't find dependent libraries

However, if I copy some specific dll files to **JAVA_HOME\jre6\bin**, my code works correctly. (I do add this path into my system environment PATH.)

Could anyone explain why the first approach by using java.library.path doesn't work? How can I know which ddl is required to place in **JAVA_HOME\jre6\bin**?

Thank you a lot~

Comment: Any chance there's some 32/64-bit issues?

Comment: @technomage I try to add my path **D:\Software x64\eclipse3.7\Kai\workspace_RealW\GunCalibration\myLib\DLLs** where my DLLs store to PATH environment variable, but it still shows me the same error. So these DLLs can only be found in JAVA_HOME\jre6\bin ? Thanks again.

Comment: Use dependency walker (http://dependencywalker.com) to determine the full list of DLLs you require, then make sure the paths to *all* of them are included in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVA_HOME\jre6\bin is effectively in the system PATH (since it's the same directory as the java.exe program which is being run), which makes any DLLs there loadable by the system.  java.library.path is mostly derived from the value of PATH, but it only affects where the VM looks for native libraries, *not* the system itself.

The VM can load any file explicitly based on the paths in java.library.path, but it cannot affect how the system looks up any dependent DLLs (other than telling the system to include the path to the initial DLL in its search -- see [MSDN for LoadLibrary[Ex]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

One alternative to copying the DLLs is to add the path to the DLLs to the PATH environment variable.